# Problems with openssl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

When I run `openssl` in terminal I get this message:

```
openssl: /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3: version `OPENSSL_3.0.3' not found (required by openssl)
```

This issue appeared after I upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.04.1 LTS.
Seems like this error is affecting other things like connecting to a VPN or installing packages.

I tried reinstalling openssl using: `sudo apt install openssl` but nothing changed.
I'm not familiar with this program so I have run out of ideas.
What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139251/discussion-on-question-by-cyberuser-problems-with-openssl).

Comment: Any idea where this `/opt/dell/dcc/libcrypro.so.3` file comes from and why it is in your library search path?

Comment: @user2233709 I don't have a clue. I have a DELL laptop hence the dell directory, but I'm not familiar with the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by doing:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3 /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3
```

I assume you have an DELL Notebook and there are some tweaks automatically installed by Ubuntu, which are getting sort of broken regarding this library.

Comment: Why not simply remove `/opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3`?

Comment: Thank you! It fixed the issue.

Comment: I also ran `sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh` afterwards to fix all Python urllib errors

Comment: I can confirm it is sufficient to just rename /opt/dell/dcc/libcrypto.so.3