# openssl3.1.1 version 'OPNESSL_3.2.0' Not found

Tags: fedora, openssl

I'm having an issue similar to here ([Problems with openssl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/717390/problems-with-openssl?newreg=c90c99d3f2df4bcab9272dbfa96647b2)), but am not sure how to translate it to my Fedora install (Fedora 28, unfortunately, I can't upgrade )

**Background:**

I'm wanted to install Python 3.11.5 to better follow a tutorial on my system. However the installer is unable to compile without a an updated openssl on the system.

I followed this installer https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-openssl-from-source-on-linux/ without issue (except the files outlined in **Configure OpenSSL Binary** already existed (so I guess the new installer takes care of it?)

**My Problem**

When I run `openssl version -a`

I get the response:

`openssl: /usr/local/ssl/lib64/libssl.so.3: version 'OPENSSL_3.2.0' not found (required by openssl)`

`openssl: /usr/local/ssl/lib64/libcrypto.so.3: version 'OPENSSL_3.2.0' not found (required by openssl)`

I'm sure the solution is copying the reference files to the right place, but I'm not sure where the correct location is.

Comment: I'd try **pyenv** to install other versions of **python** before messing with your core system libraries: https://github.com/pyenv